# Objective-c regex to see if a string has more than one number and a space?

Tags: objective-c, regex

Looking to match a regex in a string to see if it is has more than one number in a row

I am looking for things like:

```
125 blue
12
494948 word
sometext 8797879
```

So looking for anything with more than one number in a row, but I don't care if it has other characters in it.

The below is not working

```
//cleanedString is the string I pass in


NSString *myRegex = @"\\d{2,}";
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myRegex];
BOOL matches = [test evaluateWithObject:cleanedString];
return matches;
```

Comment: Tried this NSString *myRegex = @"\\[0-9][0-9]+ \\";               but it doesn't like the "\\"

Comment: in your regex above there is no space after `{2,}`, typo or not?

Comment: Mistake, but it doesn't work either.  UPDATING

Answer (score 0):

The most portable regex would be

```
[0-9]{2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using all of these with IF statements.

```
@"\\d{1,25}+ (.*)"

@"(.*) \\d{4,25}+"

@"(.*) \\d{1,25}+ (.*)"

@"\\d{1,25}+"
```